# How do I use custom CSV in my code instead of Yahoo Finance data?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm building a stock prediction neural network. The tutorial i was watching was importing the stock data from yahoo finance. I want to improve the code by making it fetch the data from a CSV file so the code can be used even if you are not connected to the internet.

What do I need to change In my code to have it use custom data from a CSV file?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM

company = '^GDAXI'

start = dt.datetime(2012,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2021,1,1)

data = web.DataReader(company, 'yahoo', start, end)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data['Close'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

prediction_days = 60

x_train = []
y_train = []

for x in range(prediction_days, len(scaled_data)):
    x_train.append(scaled_data[x-prediction_days:x, 0])
    y_train.append(scaled_data[x, 0])

x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))

#BUILD MODEL
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1)) #next day prediction

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, batch_size=32)

#TEST ON EXISTING DATA

test_start = dt.datetime(2020,1,1)
test_end = dt.datetime.now()

test_dataset = web.DataReader(company, 'yahoo', test_start, test_end)
actual_prices = test_dataset['Close'].values

total_dataset = pd.concat((data['Close'], test_dataset['Close']), axis=0)

model_inputs = total_dataset[len(total_dataset)-len(test_dataset)-prediction_days:].values
model_inputs = model_inputs.reshape(-1,1)
model_inputs = scaler.transform(model_inputs)

#PREDICTIONS ON TEST DATA
x_test = []

for x in range(prediction_days, len(model_inputs)):
    x_test.append(model_inputs[x-prediction_days:x, 0])
    
x_test = np.array(x_test)
x_test = np.reshape(x_test,(x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1],1))

predicted_prices = model.predict(x_test)
predicted_prices = scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_prices)

#PLOT
plt.plot(actual_prices, color="green", label="Actual Price")
plt.plot(predicted_prices, color="blue", label="Predicted Price")
plt.title("GER40 Share Price")
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('GER40 Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

#Predict Next Day
real_dataset = [model_inputs[len(model_inputs)+1-prediction_days:len(model_inputs+1), 0]]
real_dataset = np.array(real_dataset)
real_dataset = np.reshape(real_dataset, (real_dataset.shape[0], real_dataset.shape[1], 1))
prediction = model.predict(real_dataset)
prediction = scaler.inverse_transform(prediction)
print(f"Close: {prediction}")
```

The CSV file i'm using doesn't have headings, but i think i can add those using excel

Comment: What have you already tried? Did you look into csv reader for example?

Comment: i know how to open the file for reading with pandas or csv reader, i just don't know how to integrate it into the code. For example, i dont know what i would replace `data = web.DataReader(company, 'yahoo', start, end)` with if i used my own csv file and not a yahoo finance import

Comment: You have at least 2 options to find that out: First you could use python's debugger to ding what output a datareader gives you and find the matching version in CSV. Secondly you could look through the documentation of the datareader and figure out it's out. If you say it's going to be CSV, you should be fine using a simple CSV reader.

Comment: i want to read a csv file, my issue is that i don’t know how to integrate it into the code..i know how to import the file though

Comment: I don't have any experience with Pandas so I don't know what the return of the datareader is, but if it's comparable with CSV than you'd be able to replace the "data =" line with something like "data = csv.reader()". If the data types are not comparable, use pdb to figure out the gap and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider doing it this way.

```
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

start = '2019-06-30'
end = '2020-06-30'

tickers = ['GOOG']

thelen = len(tickers)

price_data = []
for ticker in tickers:
    prices = wb.DataReader(ticker, start = start, end = end, data_source='yahoo')[['Open','Adj Close']]
    price_data.append(prices.assign(ticker=ticker)[['ticker', 'Open', 'Adj Close']])

#names = np.reshape(price_data, (len(price_data), 1))

df = pd.concat(price_data)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

for col in df.columns: 
    print(col) 
    
#used for setting the output figure size
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 20,10
#to normalize the given input data
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
#to read input data set (place the file name inside  ' ') as shown below


df['Adj Close'].plot()
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
ntrain = 80
df_train = df.head(int(len(df)*(ntrain/100)))
ntest = -80
df_test = df.tail(int(len(df)*(ntest/100)))


#importing the packages 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM

#dataframe creation
seriesdata = df.sort_index(ascending=True, axis=0)
new_seriesdata = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(df)),columns=['Date','Adj Close'])
length_of_data=len(seriesdata)
for i in range(0,length_of_data):
    new_seriesdata['Date'][i] = seriesdata['Date'][i]
    new_seriesdata['Adj Close'][i] = seriesdata['Adj Close'][i]
#setting the index again
new_seriesdata.index = new_seriesdata.Date
new_seriesdata.drop('Date', axis=1, inplace=True)
#creating train and test sets this comprises the entire data’s present in the dataset
myseriesdataset = new_seriesdata.values
totrain = myseriesdataset[0:255,:]
tovalid = myseriesdataset[255:,:]
#converting dataset into x_train and y_train
scalerdata = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scale_data = scalerdata.fit_transform(myseriesdataset)
x_totrain, y_totrain = [], []
length_of_totrain=len(totrain)
for i in range(60,length_of_totrain):
    x_totrain.append(scale_data[i-60:i,0])
    y_totrain.append(scale_data[i,0])
x_totrain, y_totrain = np.array(x_totrain), np.array(y_totrain)
x_totrain = np.reshape(x_totrain, (x_totrain.shape[0],x_totrain.shape[1],1))


#LSTM neural network
lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_totrain.shape[1],1)))
lstm_model.add(LSTM(units=50))
lstm_model.add(Dense(1))
lstm_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adadelta')
lstm_model.fit(x_totrain, y_totrain, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
#predicting next data stock price
myinputs = new_seriesdata[len(new_seriesdata) - (len(tovalid)+1) - 60:].values
myinputs = myinputs.reshape(-1,1)
myinputs  = scalerdata.transform(myinputs)
tostore_test_result = []
for i in range(60,myinputs.shape[0]):
    tostore_test_result.append(myinputs[i-60:i,0])
tostore_test_result = np.array(tostore_test_result)
tostore_test_result = np.reshape(tostore_test_result,(tostore_test_result.shape[0],tostore_test_result.shape[1],1))
myclosing_priceresult = lstm_model.predict(tostore_test_result)
myclosing_priceresult = scalerdata.inverse_transform(myclosing_priceresult)
    
totrain = df_train
tovalid = df_test

#predicting next data stock price
myinputs = new_seriesdata[len(new_seriesdata) - (len(tovalid)+1) - 60:].values

#  Printing the next day’s predicted stock price. 
print(len(tostore_test_result));
print(myclosing_priceresult);
```

Final Result:

[[1396.532]]

Comment: this doesn’t help with my issue, i want to import data from a csv file, not yahoo